# Modelagem Spring JPA Pessoa -> PessoaFisica -> Funcionario

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Fiz a modelagem de dados (UML) mas na hora de implementar estou com dúvida de como fazer.

Queria que tivesse somente uma tabela Pessoa.

Nessa tabela pessoa eu teria o campo `tipoPessoa("p","f")` e os campos se a pessoa é cliente, barbeiro, atendente, fornecedor, fabricante, etc.

Queria fazer essa implementação em Spring JPA que vi que é bem fácil de usar.

**Aqui vai basicamente como quero que fique a table no banco:**

[image: Aqui vai basicamente como quero que fique a table no banco:]

**Aqui é como quero que fique no java:**

[image: Aqui é como quero que fique no java:]

Sei que essa relação entre pessoas e tipos poderia ser manytomany gerando uma tabela a mais, mas pra este projeto quero fazer assim mesmo.

A dúvida é como faco pro Spring entender que quero que fique tudo na mesma tabela com campos Ex: `pess.forn = "f", "t"`

Comment: Independente da tecnologia usado não é uma boa ideia modelar o banco de dados diferente da memória. Não gosto de nenhum dos modelos. Esse modelo é furado na vida real.

Answer (score 2):

Você [pode usar](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance) a estratégia de JOIN **Single Table**, na qual o Hibernate cria uma única tabela para cada hierarquia. Esta também é a estratégia padrão escolhida pelo JPA se você não especificar uma explicitamente.

Para efeito didático, vou mostrar um exemplo definido esta estratégia explicitamente:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="tipoPessoa", 
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Pessoa {
    @Id
    private long idPessoa;
    private String contato;
    // demais campos
}
```

Acima eu criei uma tabela `Pessoa` e disse que para diferenciar entre as diferentes pessoas (jurídica e física) vou usar o campo `tipoPessoa`. A informação que vai no `tipoPessoa` é definida nas classes filhas pela anotação `@DiscriminatorValue`. Veja abaixo:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("pf")
public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa {
    private String cpf;
    // demais campos
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("pj")
public class PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa {
    private String cnpj;
    // demais campos
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("cliente")
public class Cliente extends PessoaFisica {
    // demais campos do cliente
}
```

Comment: e como ficaria a parte das colunas para diferenciar se é cliente, funcionario, fornecedor(pess.forn = 'F') ?

Comment: @BrunoBrito, você pode extender o `PessoaFisica` em outra entidade e adicionar um `@DiscriminatorValue` para cada entidade `Cliente`, `Funcionario` , etc. Não testei mas acho que funciona! Editei minha pergunta com esta sugestão.

Answer (score -1):

Vc pode criar uma tabela pess da seguinte forma:

```
create table pess(
id NUMBER not null,
email              VARCHAR2(100),
forn VARCHAR2(1) default 'f')
```

OBS: o script acima tem como exemplo o ORACLE.

A classe Person:

```
public class Person{
 private Long id;
 private String email;
 private String forn;
}
```

Quando vc for fazer os inserts vc aplica a sua lógica de inserir somente valores do tipo 'f' ou 'j'. Vc pode utilizar o **flyway** para ler os seus scripts sql. Caso não conheça o flaway, recomendo q vc pesquise sobre. Ele ira lhe dar uma liberdade para criar a suas tabelas.